# ¿como cerrar teclado despues de que se pierde el foco de un textBox?

Tags: c#, wpf

tambien si se puede indicarle en que posicion de la pantalla donde aparesca

```
    static string dirTeclado = "C:\\Program Files\\Common Files\\Microsoft Shared\\ink\\TabTip.exe";

    public static void ShowTeclado()
    {
        Process.Start(dirTeclado);
    }
    public static void hideTeclado()
    {
        //Cerrar Teclado
    }
```

Comment: ¿Qué comportamiento debe tener hideTeclado, cerrarlo terminando el proceso o cerrarlo a cómo sucede al dar click en el botón cerrar de la ventana?

Comment: terminando el proceso

Answer (score 0):

Esto depende de algunas cosas, como la arquitectura o la versión de Windows, te dejo el caso de Windows 10 x64:

Primero: Debes ir a las propiedades del proyecto y en BUILD/Compilar debes colocar el Platform Target/Destino de plataforma en X64 y no en AnyCPU, si no haces esto es posible que lo que sigue no funcione.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Segundo: Abres el teclado así:

```
Process.Start("osk.exe");
```

Y para cerrarlo puedes hacerlo así (con try-catch claro):

```
foreach (var process in Process.GetProcessesByName("osk"))
{
   process.Kill();
}
```

Ahora bien, hay varios puntos que considerar también, por ejemplo:

Es posible que en ciertos equipos debas ejecutar el software con privilegios de Administrador para que pueda cerrar el teclado en pantalla

EDIT: El evento para cerrar el teclado lo ubicas en el LostFocus, así:

```
private void TextBox_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                foreach (var process in Process.GetProcessesByName("osk"))
                {
                    process.Kill();
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
               //algo  falló al intentar cerrar el teclado  
            }
        }
```

Un saludo.

Comment: no funciono, y cuando cambio de ventana da error de formato incorrecto pero es por la configuracion , el equipo tiene win 7

Answer (score 0):

Creo que algo así te servirá:

```
private static string dirTeclado = "C:\\Program Files\\Common Files\\Microsoft Shared\\ink\\TabTip.exe";
private static Process process = null;

public static void ShowTeclado()
{
    if (process != null) HideTeclado();
    Process.Start(dirTeclado);
}
public static void HideTeclado()
{
    if (process != null) {
        try {
            process.kill();
        } catch() { }
        process = null;
    }
}
```

¡Suerte!